# Sqlite running total fails when executed from Embarcadero Delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi, select, syntax-error

I have unsuccessfully tried to execute a `SELECT` from inside Delphi XE7. The same query perfectly works when run from inside SqliteExpert (or any other similar app).

I have trie several variations of the `SELECT`, but all of them fail with the same error message.

I give you an example of the select I would like to run:

```
FDQry.SQL.Clear;
FDQry.SQL.Add(SELECT num, account, amount, SUM(amount) OVER ( ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS RunningTotal FROM MyTable where account='NFI');
FDQry.Open;
```

I get this error:

> " " near "(" syntax error "

Comment: Probably the version of SQLite is prior to 3.25.0 when window functions were introduced.

Comment: SQLite 3.25.0 was released 15th September 2018 while Delphi XE7 2nd September, 2014. You need something more recent on the SQLite side than what came with XE7.

Comment: Your SQL command is a string, and any string constant in Delphi should be quoted by single quote: FDQry.SQL.Add('.....'); and 2 single quote marks represent ' in a string constant. That must be what you need.

Comment: Sorry about the missing quotes. That is a typing mistake. I am using sqlite3.dll version 3.38.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is a error in the example, but you need to use quotes inside the Add. The parameter is a string after all.

```
FDQry.SQL.Add(' ..... ');
```

Comment: Missing quotes are a typing mistake, sorry

Comment: What happens then if you try
`FDQry.SQL.Add('SELECT num, account, amount, SUM(amount) OVER ( ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS RunningTotal FROM MyTable where account='+QuotedStr('NFI'));`

Comment: Same error message .. Thanks anyway